# Identify exact line on which application got crashed?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

How can I identify exact line of program on which my application crashed? Is there any tool to tell me which line in which source file has crashed the application?

I am using C/C++, MFC, and VC++.

Comment: "Debugging" is the answer, you could also throw exceptions and use a line number macro

Comment: I was going to suggest to use Visual Studio, but since you are already using Visual Studio, I guess you'd have to solve the [PEBCAC](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/PEBCAC) first.

Comment: Build "Debug", not "Release". Run with F5.

Comment: thanks all for your answers and comments. But the problem is crash is not generated all time. At our development center crash is not being generated, it is at the customer end it got crashed sometimes on any prticular condition and it is hard to reproduced at our end.That's why I am already using logging mechanisam which tells us application got crashed along with module name (it showing us the ntdll.dll). Thta's why I want to know any mechanisam available which just log the line number of code along with the modulname.

Answer (score 0):

Use gdb to see where your application crash. For linux, use `gdb --args (Application command line)`

use breakpoints for stepping into various functions. And if you run into crash, use bt to backtrace the code.

Though there are many many things in gdb, my aim was to give just the pointer, where you can begin.

Comment: Remember to tell the compiler to add debugging information.

Comment: This probably should be a question in itself, but can you even debug microsoft visual c++ with gdb?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: yes, if you like pain (gdb doesn't grok VC's debug info)

Answer (score 0):

For run time (non-debugger attached) exceptions I like using "BOOST_EXCEPTIONS" because the BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION macro attaches BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION, **FILE** and **LINE** to the exception.

But the best way is to compile in debug mode and run with a debugger attached. If you're using visual studio (which with VC++, you probably already are) move to debug mode and run it. When an un-handled exception is thrown, it should bring you right there.

If you want to catch handled exceptions, from the Menu bar, Debug->Exceptions. Checking all of these will make the exceptions caught by the debugger, even when they are handled. Though people using exceptions for non-fatal errors can make this SUPER ANNOYING...

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot by what you mean by 'crash'. But assuming that you mean an exception occured in your app, then the [`EXCEPTION_RECORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082(v=vs.85).aspx) structure will contain the exact address where the exception occurred, in other words the IP that was executed when the exception was raised. On Windows C++ exception use SEH. Read  the timeless A [Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx) to understand SEH.

You can retrieve the exception info from a crash dump (see [`ecxr` Display Exception Context Record](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562945(v=vs.85).aspx)) or you can instruct debuggers to break on exception. [Dr. Watso](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308538)n will create dumps for you when crash occurs.